# Attach to IIS on F5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a library project in Visual Studio which is deployed as part of web site.
Now I debug it attaching every time to IIS process, but it is really irritating.

Is there a way to configure C# Library project to attach to IIS on F5? I am using VS2010 and VS2012.

**Small update**
I have usually more than one w3wp process running on my machine.

Comment: There appears to be a bug currently when using **Local IIS + F5** where you get unwanted CPU cycles for some reason. I reported it https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/High-devenvexe-CPU-when-debugging-NET/1423504. So ironically I found this question because I was forced into attaching instead of pressing F5.

Answer (score 6):

I do use the [AttachTo](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0265ab0-df51-4100-8e10-1f84403c4cd0) Visual Studio Extension. It provides shortcuts under the tool menu:
[image]

And attaching the debugger takes half a second. A really great tool :)

Comment: What about multiple w3wp process? Can I choose which App Pool should it attach to?

Comment: @Garath I did not try in such scenario, I'm using that in developement environment

Comment: I will try this extension +1

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's available by default.

You could use reattach : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8cccc206-b9de-42ef-8f5a-160ad0f017ae for easing the process to attach every time.

Comment: It is really interesting, I will explore this extension

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**
I think you could do something like as below in the .csproj file to configure the project in IIS.

- As you open the project in visual studio it will automatically configure the project as web site in local IIS.
- When you will press F5 it will run from IIS.
- Change the `<IISUrl>http://www.site.com/MySampleWebsite</IISUrl>` to your specific while copying.

  ```
  <Project>
    <!-- Some more tags here such as PropertyGroup, and Imports, etc -->
    <ProjectExtensions>
      <VisualStudio>
          <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
              <WebProjectProperties>
                  <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
                  <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
                  <DevelopmentServerPort>8080</DevelopmentServerPort>
                  <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
                  <IISUrl>http://www.site.com/MySampleWebsite</IISUrl>
                  <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
                  <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
                  <CustomServerUrl>
                  </CustomServerUrl>
                  <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
              </WebProjectProperties>
          </FlavorProperties>
      </VisualStudio>
    </ProjectExtensions>
  </Project>
  ```

**Solution 2:**

*Use of keyboard shortcut*

- Keyboard solution steps

  1. Press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
  2. Press <kbd>w</kbd>, So it would highlight to w3wp.exe process in the list.
  3. Select all the w3wp process items at once.
  4. Select Ok and you're done.

**Solution 3:**

*Configuration of Web application project in IIS via Visual Studio properties window*

You could configure the settings from visual studio wizard when your project is an *web application project*. Just right click on the project and open `Properties` > select 'Web' from left side menu and then check the settings from below screen. Configure your website url by checking `Use local IIS Web server` then below it `Override applicationroot URL` and enter the url path as shown in image or as per your needs.

[image: Configuration of Web application project in IIS via Visual Studio properties window]

*PS: Solution 3 is similar to Solution 1 but follows visual studio wizard for acheiving the same. But Solution 3 seems having less visually options regarding the IIS configurations for Virtual Directory and Application Pool.*

Comment: I will explore solution. Thanks for shortcuts there are really useful +1

Comment: But my project is not web app. It is a class library, which is used by web app. I am developing portable area

Answer (score 0):

Reattach to process is now supported in Visual Studio natively, you don't need a plugin.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger